# Jquery Loop and display json data in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting this data via getJSON which is returning this data under variable called results.

Here is the data:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "messages": [
        {
            "text": "Message 1",
            "username": "bot",
            "type": "message",
            "subtype": "bot_message",
            "ts": "1454394770.000002"
        },
        {
            "text": "Message 2",
            "username": "bot",
            "type": "message",
            "subtype": "bot_message",
            "ts": "1447656207.000002"
        },
        {
            "user": "5434543",
            "type": "message",
            "subtype": "ch_join",
            "text": "<@U0456TA8|tre> has joined",
            "ts":654565.444"
        }
    ],
    "has_more": false
}
```

I know how to add one of them to my textarea:

```
$("#myTextarea").val(results.messages[0].text);
```

My question is ... How do I add all of it into my textarea?

Comment: Side note - it is bad practice to have objects in an array that have different structures/attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var output = "";
jQuery.each(results.messages , function (index, element){
  output += element.text + "something to put between the text perhaps?";
});
$("#myTextarea").val(output);
```

Comment: Why use `jQuery` and not `$`?

Comment: force of habit, usually developing for cms (joomla wordpress etc) and using $ can get you into some strange situations if code from many different developers is being executed at the same time. jQuery is foolproof.

Comment: _@Elentriel_ oh, I see.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop in:

```
    var _val = $("#myTextarea").val(); // Fetching the new value and adding it to previous value
    [].forEach.call(results.messages, function (inst) {
        _val += inst.text;
    });

    $("#myTextarea").val(_val); //setting it as a new value of textarea.
```

Comment: Should you not append it to a variable and then assign it to textarea? I mean dom interaction is the most expensive part of js and we should minimize it.

Comment: @Rajesh : Better approach.. Check updated answer.. Thanks mate!

Comment: I believe you are missing part where you aspend `inst` to val

Comment: @void `Downvotes?` Because you dont answer the question

Comment: I did not downvote you, but if i'm not missing something, arent you adding the value of the text area result.messages.length times and then putting it back? You should add the inst.text (i suppose? not sure) for each message instead

Comment: Fish! My bad, Check it now.. should be fine.. Sorry people/